# How to change my OS X and make it as much threads as possible?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, macos

It seems that there are some limitations as for OSX when it's about threads, check out this :  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3854.

I've been trying to use ruby with a system that is responsible of opening as much TCPs threads as needed, To reproduce the problem in ruby I used the following code :

```
10000.times { |n| p n; Thread.new { sleep  60 } }
```

When I run the code above I keep getting this error after printing out around 2022 threads :

```
ThreadError: unable to create new native thread
  initialize at org/jruby/RubyThread.java:382
         new at org/jruby/RubyThread.java:301
      (root) at main.rb:1
       times at org/jruby/RubyFixnum.java:273
      (root) at main.rb:1
```

That's with Jruby implementation, but it's the same for all the other implementations, actually it's not related to ruby itself, like if you do the same with cpp you would face the same problem :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ulimit.h>

void thread_main(void *ptr)
{
  sleep(60);
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  pthread_t threads[10000];

  for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if(pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, (void *)thread_main, NULL) != 0) {
      perror("thread test");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to maximise the number of the threads to use all the resources there ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anyway to maximise the number of the threads to use all the resources there?

Change your design. 10000 physical threads is just wasting resources -- it will consume tons of memory and spend (pretty much) all of its time context switching.

Limit your program to 16 threads (as a starting point) and approach the problem differently. Your program will receive much more CPU time this way (read: it will be many many times faster than using 1000+ threads). Throwing more threads at the problem (as illustrated in the OP) will just slow your system to a crawl (if it were to honor your request  -- see Parallel Slowdown).

See also "[Thread Costs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW7)" for OS X.

Comment: I have no other alternative, except to use some other language like erlang which has it's out schedular to map the processes. i'm using epoll not select so the context switching not supposed to be the main problem, I don't want to use 10k threads for better performance, my server supposed to work as a main handler who talk to different social networks through xmpp, so it's not an option to use like 16 threads, i'm using threads since it's less expensive than spawning a processes.

Comment: but after all , i'll need to have one (thread/processes) for each TCP connection and I want the system to use the whole available resources, I tried to change the ulimit but with no luck, in ubuntu case, the system will stop creating threads when there is no available resources left, how am I supposed to achieve that with OS X

Comment: @EkiEqbal pass an array to epoll, rather than creating a thread for each file descriptor then epolling one file descriptor from each thread: https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/ also, OS X does not have epoll. it has poll and kevents. so, i'm still not seeing a need for more that 16 threads.